# Kinvey iOS query all users

Tags: ios, kinvey

From Kinvey documentation this is the method to use for querying users:

> To query the user collection we recommend instead using
>   +[KCSUserDiscovery lookupUsersForFieldsAndValues:completionBlock:progressBlock:]. This
>   method allows you to supply a dictionary of exact matches for special
>   fields.
>
> Fields for lookup:
>
> - KCSUserAttributeUsername
> - KCSUserAttributeSurname
> - KCSUserAttributeGivenname
> - KCSUserAttributeEmail
> - KCSUserAttributeFacebookId

```
 [KCSUserDiscovery lookupUsersForFieldsAndValues:@{ KCSUserAttributeSurname : @"Smith"}
                                    completionBlock:^(NSArray *objectsOrNil, NSError *errorOrNil) {
                                        if (errorOrNil == nil) {
                                            //array of matching KCSUser objects
                                            NSLog(@"Found %d Smiths", objectsOrNil.count);
                                        } else {
                                            NSLog(@"Got An error: %@", errorOrNil);
                                        }
                                    }
                                      progressBlock:nil];
```

But if I send empty dictionary, I get an error. So what to put in dictionary to get all the users?

Thank you guys, happy holidays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all the users, you can use the regular app data querying API.

For example,

```
KCSAppdataStore* store = [KCSAppdataStore storeWithCollection:[KCSCollection userCollection] options:nil];
[store queryWithQuery:[KCSQuery query] withCompletionBlock:^(NSArray *objectsOrNil, NSError *errorOrNil) {
    //handle completion
} withProgressBlock:nil];
```

This will get a list of all the users the active user has permission to access.